# How can one write lock a zarr store during append?

Tags: python, zarr

Is there some way to lock a `zarr` store when using `append`?

I have already found out the hard way that using `append` with multiple processes is a bad idea (the batches to append aren't aligned with the batch size of the store). The reason I'd like to use multiple processes is because I need to transform the original arrays before appending them to the `zarr` store. It would be nice to be able to block other processes from writing concurrently but still perform the transformations in parallel, then append their data in series.

**Edit:**

Thanks to jdehesa's suggestion, I became aware of the synchronization part of the documentation. I passed a `ProcessSynchronizer` pointing to a folder on disk to my array at creation in the main thread, then spawned a bunch of worker processes with `concurrent.futures` and passed the array to all the workers for them to append their results. I could see that the `ProcessSynchronizer` did something, as the folder I pointed it to filled with files, but the array that my workers write to ended up missing rows (compared to when written from a single process).

Comment: I suppose you have to pass a [`synchronizer`](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/sync.html) on [creation](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/creation.html) to protect write access.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for your comment, It helped me find the relevant documentation.

Comment: @jdehesa Tried the `ProcessSynchronizer`, i can see that it does write some stuff to its folder, but had no effect on output. I'm still missing rows in the result. I also disabled threading in blosc, which also didn't solve the issue.